# find X, such that U=VX

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{u_{1},u_{2},\ldots,u_{n}\}$, $\{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}\}$ be two bases for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and define $U=[u_{1}\mid u_{2}\mid\cdots\mid u_{n}]$, (that is, $U$ is the $n\times n$ matrix whose columns are the vectors $u_{1},u_{2},\ldots,u_{n}$, and similarly for $V$). Prove that there exists an invertible, $n\times n$ matrix $X$ such that $U=VX$. Can someone give ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The columns of $U$ and $V$ form a basis and hence $U$ and $V$ must be invertible (notice that $X=0$ is the only solution to $VX = 0$ by linear independence).  Set $X = V^{-1}U$.

$$U = V V^{-1}U = VX$$

It should be easy to check from here that $X^{-1} = U^{-1}V$.

Comment: This seems roundabout; why not just set $X=V^{-1}U$.

Comment: @vadim123 Good point.